# How to change text to upper case or lower case depending on string length in Angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement text formatting on a string called name.Once the string is entered into the html form,upon click of a save button, the new string format should be rendered below the form.
The string  should either be changed to uppercase or lowercase depending on string length.
If string length is even,the string should be changed to uppercase, if string length is odd,string should be changed to lowercase.

I have put the logic for changing the text case inside the  'formatFactory' factory.The format method inside the 'formatFactory' is responsible for changing text case.

formattingFactory.js

```
app.factory('formatFactory', function(){

var formattingFactoryObject = {};

formattingFactoryObject.format = function(name) {

    if(name.length % 2 == 0) {
        name.toUpperCase();
    }else{
        name.toLowerCase();
    }
}


});
```

I have the following service that is responsible for saving session data i.e name and nickname strings

sessionService.js

```
angular.module('app').service('sessionService',[
'$window',
//the $window object provides angular access to the browser's window object
sessionService
]);

function sessionService($window) {
  this.save = save;
  this.get = get;
  this.clear = clear;

function save(key, value) {

    $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);


 }

 function get(key, value) {
    return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);


}
```

The following is my controller.I have called the method for changing string case right before the method for saving session data inside vm.setServiceSession method

sessionController.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('sessionController',[
'sessionService','formatFactory',

function sessionController(sessionService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getServiceSession = function() {
        vm.model = {
            name: sessionService.get('name'),
            nickname: sessionService.get('nickname'),
            status: 'Retrieved by service on ' + new Date()
        };
    }

    vm.setServiceSession = function() {

        formattingFactoryObject.format(name);

        sessionService.save('name', vm.model.name);

        sessionService.save('nickname', vm.model.nickname);
        vm.getServiceSession();

    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <title>Services and Factories</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="sessionController as vm">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Services and Factories</h1>
    <div class ="form-group row">
        <div class ="col-sm-4">
            <label>Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-8">
            <input type = "text" class ="form-control" ng-model ="vm.model.name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="form-group row">
        <div class ="col-sm-4">
            <label>Nickname</label>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-sm-8">
            <input type = "text" class ="form-control" ng-model ="vm.model.nickname">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group row">
        <div class = "col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <input type = "button" ng-click = "vm.setServiceSession()" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Save"/>
            <input type = "button" ng-click ="vm.getServiceSession()" class = "btn btn-default" value = "Retrieve from Service"/>


        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{vm.model | json }}</pre>



</div>
```

The problem with the above code is that it doesnt change the string case and i cant figure out why.

Comment: `String.toLowerCase` will not update value. It returns a new string. You will have to assign it. try `name = name.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the new value of `name.toLowerCase()` and `name.toUpperCase()` to a new value `name` as @Rajesh said in his comment, and of course return `name` in the end in your factory. You also have to format the `$scope.model.name` while saving it in the localStorage like this :

```
sessionService.save('name', formatFactory.formattingFactoryObject($scope.model.name));
```

You also need to refactor your factory.

I created a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DG24c/349/).